# Google Sheets Query() Function Returning Unexpected Data

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language, google-sheets-query

I am having trouble with the QUERY() function in Google Sheets. I'm not certain I am using the correct function to generate the required data. I am far more comfortable  with T-SQL, but my wife needs a mailing list generated from her current google sheets.

**The facts:**

- Sheet2 is populated with data from B3:K150
- I have a list of names in Sheet2, Column B.
- I have a list of addresses in Sheet2, Column G
- Sheet1 contains no data other than the data populated in Column B (See below)
- Sheet1, Column B is populated with a unique list of names from
  Sheet2, Column B using =Unique('Sheet2'!$B$3:$B$150).

**Goal:**

- I would like to populate **Sheet1, Column C** with **Sheet2, Column G** 
  WHERE Sheet1(ColumnB) = Sheet2(ColumnB)

Obviously, using SQL, we would write this as such:

```
SELECT [Sheet1].[ColumnB]
      ,[Sheet1].[ColumnC] 
FROM [Sheet1] 
    INNER JOIN [Sheet2] 
        ON [Sheet1].[ColumnB] = [Sheet2].[ColumnB]
```

**What I have tried:**

INSERT the following formula into Sheet1!C3:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!B3:K150,"SELECT G WHERE B ='"&Sheet1!B3:B150&"'",0)
```

**Sheet screenshots:**

[image]
[image]

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked well for me:

```
=unique(query(Sheet2!B3:G150,"select B,G"))
```

as posted by user: **pnuts** in comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Sheet1C3 `=Arrayformula(if(B3:B=Sheet2!B3:B,Sheet2!G3:G,""))`  Let me know if you need me to explain the formula.